# Is there a tip/trick to using with( ) with command that output a df

Tags: r

Below is an example of what I am eluding to:

```
tmp = as.data.frame(pre[grepl("Sub-visible", pre$Name) & pre$Upc == "PRDS-000853", ])
with(tmp, split(tmp, Name))
```

Here tmp is variable that is created as a place holder, which is used in the second  line.  I find myself do this quite a bit, hence wanted to know if there is a way to do without assigning the command (which outputs the input used in the `split ()` function), something like this

```
with(as.data.frame(pre[grepl("Sub-visible", pre$Name) & pre$Upc == "PRDS-000853", ]), split(Name))
```

which is obviously wrong.  I can thought maybe dplyr's pipe operators and `do()` but this is also wrong:

```
as.data.frame(pre[grepl("Sub-visible", pre$Name) & pre$Upc == "PRDS-000853", ]) %>% 
do(split(., Name))
```

But might be missing a simple tip/trick just using the base R commands.  Thanks.

Comment: Replacing `do` with `with` should do the trick in the pipe example: `as.data.frame(...) %>% with(split(., Name))`

Comment: A pipe with a code block will do: `as.data.frame(...) %>% {split(., .$name)}`

Comment: Awesome @ArtemSokolov

Comment: Awesome @MrFlick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer with provided in the comments, 2 way:

Replacing do with with should do the trick in the pipe example: `as.data.frame(...) %>% with(split(., Name))` – @ArtemSokolov

OR

A pipe with a code block will do: `as.data.frame(...) %>% {split(., .$name)}` - @MrFlick